# How to move point on arc?

Tags: java, awt

I am writing an app that is simulating RobotArm movement. What I want to achieve, and where I have couple of problems is moving a Point on arc (180degree) that is arm range of movement.
I am moving an arm by grabbing with mouse end of arm (Elbow, the Point I was talking about), robot can have multiple arms with diffrent arm lenghts.

If u can help me with this part, I'd be grateful.

This is what I have so far, drawing function:

```
public void draw(Graphics graph) { 
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graph.create();

    graph.setColor(color);
    graph.fillOval(location.x - 4, location.y - 4, point.width, point.height); //Draws elbow
    if (parentLocation != null) {
        graph.setColor(Color.black);
        graph.drawLine(location.x, location.y, parentLocation.x, parentLocation.y); //Connects to parent

        if (arc == null) {
            angle = new Double(90 - getAngle(parentInitLocation));
            arc = new Arc2D.Double(parentLocation.x - (parentDistance * 2 / 2), parentLocation.y - (parentDistance * 2 / 2), parentDistance * 2, parentDistance * 2,
                    90 - getAngle(parentInitLocation), 180, Arc2D.OPEN); //Draws an arc if not drawed yet.
        }
        else if (angle != null) //if parent is moved, angle is moved also
        {
            arc = new Arc2D.Double(parentLocation.x - (parentDistance * 2 / 2), parentLocation.y - (parentDistance * 2 / 2), parentDistance * 2, parentDistance * 2,
                    angle, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);
        }
        g2d.draw(arc);
    }
    if (spacePanel.getElbows().size() > level + 1) {//updates all childElbows position
        updateChild(graph);
    }
}
```

I just do not know how to prevent moving Point moving outside of arc line. It can not be inside or outside arc, just on it.

**Here I wanted to put a screenshot, sadly I don't have enough rep. Am I allowed to put link to this?**

Maybe you got other ways how to achieve this kind of thing.

Here is the image:
[image]

Red circle is actual state, and green one is what I want to do.

**EDIT2:** As requested, repo link: https://github.com/dspoko/RobotArm

Comment: put an external link to your screenshot

Comment: Post a link to your screenshot and someone will add it to your question

Comment: Thanks for the info, updated first post.

Comment: What's the difference between `parentDistance * 2 / 2` and `parentDistance`? (None.) So what are you trying to do? You may just need parentheses adjustment.

Comment: It will help to include code defining `location` and `parentlocation` and `arc`... `angle` ... `level` ... etc. Maybe passing those as parameters would help get help. Or provide a working (except for bugs) program or a context in which the method could be called.

Comment: I added link to github repo, I hope it would help you.

Comment: Short answer: Point `location` = location of this elbow, Point `parentLocation` = location of parentElbow and level is level of this particular elbow in whole arm starting from 0(lowest level, root). `arc` is Arc2D from java.awt.geom, and `angle` is just an angle between 2 points(current and parent), null before this method.